# How to have particles pointing away from mesh?

Tags: particles

[image]

I'd like to have the flat side of the left mesh parallel to each face where it's attached. "Phase rotation" won't do it because it doesn't influence the right axis and so on.
The file: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rotating your object in edit mode.

[image: Rotation]